# PROPEL - get the sql query

Tags: sql, propel

How can I get the sql query using this kind statement with propel?

```
$books = BookQuery::create()
  ->filterByTitle('War And Peace')
  ->find();
```

I need to log the query for debugging purpose

```
query ['SELECT book.* from `book` WHERE book.TITLE = War And Peace' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$books->toString()` method.